# Why can law of limits not be used

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be bounded (but not necessarily convergent) i.e there exists $M>0$ such that $|a_n| \leq  M $ for all $n$ in natural numbers. Now consider $(b_n)$ with $b_n := \frac{a_n}{n}$

a) explain why you can not use algebra of limits with $\frac{1}{n}$ and $(a_n)$

b) show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual limit laws tell us that if $a_n$ is a convergent sequence, then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = \left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n\right)\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\right) = \left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n\right) \cdot 0 = 0.$$

But since we don't know that $a_n$ is convergent, the above argument doesn't go through. Sure, its true that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = 0$$

but you'll have to use a slightly more sophisticated argument to demonstrate this.

*Edit*. I see that there is a second part to your question. Frankly, this is not a difficult exercise, and I encourage you to toy with the problem and solve it yourself. You'll learn more that way. If you've fooled around with it for half an hour and cannot crack it, post a new question detailing what you've tried and people will be more willing to help.

Here's a hint though: Since $a_n$ is bounded, consider fixed but arbitrary $x$ and $y$ such that $x \leq a_n$ and $a_n \leq y$ for all natural $n$. Compute the limit of $x/n$ and $y/n$, and then apply the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

*Edit 2*. To see that boundedness does not necessarily imply convergence, consider the sequence $(0,1,0,1,0,1,\cdots)$.

Comment: I'd suggest using $a_n=(-1)^n$ as an example of a bounded sequence that doesn't converge to help make your point.

Comment: @postmortes, thanks, I edited with a similar example.

Answer (score 1):

For a) you cant use this propery of limit if one of them is 0 or infinity .

b) 
$0 \leq b_n \leq \frac{M}{n}$ and by the squeeze theorem the limit is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Well we need to be absolutely clear about the rules of limits. In this case the rule of limit being discussed is $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}b_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}\cdot\lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n}$$ **provided that both $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n}$ exist.**

In the question we have $1/n \to 0$ but we don't know for certain whether $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}$ exists and hence the above rule can't be used. However there is another rule to the rescue called the Sandwich Rule:

*If $a_{n} \leq b_{n} \leq c_{n}$ for all values of $n$ after a certain point and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}c_{n} = L$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n} = L$.*

In this question we have $b_{n} = a_{n}/n$ and clearly we have $-M \leq a_{n} \leq M$ so that $-M/n \leq b_{n} \leq M/n$. Taking limits when $n \to \infty$ and using Sandwich rule mentioned above (in *italics*) we get $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n} = 0$.

Note that apart from the limit rules for $+,-,\times, /$ we also have limit rules for inequalities (like Sandwich rule) which are important in solving many limit problems.

**Update**: One more useful rule dealing with inequalities:

*If $a_{n} \leq b_{n}$ for all $n$ after a certain point and both $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n}$ exist then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n}$.*

The conclusion in this rule holds even if we have strict inequality $a_{n} < b_{n}$ i.e. *limits always tend to weaken the inequalities.*

Also note that Sandwich rule can not be deduced from this rule because in Sandwich we don't assume existence of the limit of the sequence being sandwiched between two other sequences.